# Validation fails when customizing django form in template

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-templates

I made a django form with two fields start date and end date and made a formset. When I use the formset in template as

```
{{ myformset.management_form }}

{% for form in myformset %}
<p>For period {{ forloop.counter }}</p>
{{ form.as_table }}
<br/>
{% endfor %}
<input  type = "submit"  value = "See Results" id = "daterangeresult">
```

I got the form with these two fields in two different row. And for multiple forms, it seems not good in looking as all fields are in different row. I then changed to make these two fields to display in a single row as follows

```
{{ myformset.management_form }}
{% for form in myformset %}
<p>For period {{ forloop.counter }}</p>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Start Date {{form.start_date}}</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>End Date {{form.end_date}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
{% endfor %}
<input  type = "submit"  value = "See Results" id = "daterangeresult">
```

Then this formset fails to validate my form fields which I have validated in 
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from functools import partial
from datetime import date
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'dateinput'})

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())

    def clean(self):
        if (self.cleaned_data.get('start_date') >= self.cleaned_data.get('end_date')):
            raise forms.ValidationError( 'Start date must be less than end date')
        elif(self.cleaned_data.get('start_date') > date.today() or self.cleaned_data.get('end_date') > date.today()):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Date can not be greater than today')
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

How to get two things simultaneously the form field validation and customised display of form in template?

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend updating the form definitions to include a label and a help_text.  I don't know which version you are using but here is a good place to start: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

Then, in the template you can just do `{{ form.start_date.label_tag }}`, `{{ form.start_date }}`, and `{{ form.start_date.help_text }}` whenever you want to place those into the form.

Second, for the validation issue, you might, instead of overriding clean, override clean_*fieldname*. In your case `clean_start_date` and `clean_end_date`.  Once you have those set up for can do

```
def clean_end_date(self):
    start = self.cleaned_data['start_date'] 
    end = self.cleaned_data['end_date'] 

    if start > end:
        ...do stuff...
```